# Spring, Hibernate, C3P0 and Jetty

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jetty, c3p0

I inherited a project and am trying to get it to run via jetty:run but to no avail.  Works fine using run-war or run-exploded, but cant seem to nail down issue with plain old run.  Its giving me the following stack:

```
2012-06-28 15:02:32.247:INFO:/:Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
WARN [main] JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions(233) | SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
ERROR [main] JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions(234) | Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO))
WARN [main] SettingsFactory.buildSettings(147) | Could not obtain connection to query metadata
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO))
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:855)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:540)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2833)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2829)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1840)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:814)
```

/src/main/resources/applicationContext-resources.xml

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:mail.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" >
    <property name="driverClass"  value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="8"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="8"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="32"/>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="600"/>
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="0"/>
    <property name="maxStatements" value="0"/>
    <property name="maxStatementsPerConnection" value="0"/>
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="3"/>
    <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="3"/>
    <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="1000"/>
    <property name="autoCommitOnClose" value="false"/>
    <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="14400"/>
    <property name="forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions" value="false"/>
    <property name="numHelperThreads" value="20"/>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="false"/>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="false"/>
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="select id from xtcirc101themes where rownum = 1"/>
    <property name="maxAdministrativeTaskTime" value="0"/>
    <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" value="false"/>
    <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="0"/>
    <property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="false"/>
    <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="0"/>
    <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="0"/>
    <property name="usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

/src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            .
            .
            .
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Context Configurations in /WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:/applicationContext-resources.xml
        classpath:/applicationContext-dao.xml
        classpath:/applicationContext-service.xml
        classpath*:/applicationContext.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml
        /WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext*.xml
        /WEB-INF/classes/tbmJobs*.xml
        /WEB-INF/xfire-servlet.xml
        /WEB-INF/security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

/src/main/resources/jdbc.properties

```
jdbc.driverClassName=${jdbc.driverClassName}
jdbc.url=${jdbc.url}
jdbc.username=${jdbc.username}
jdbc.password=${jdbc.password}

hibernate.dialect=${hibernate.dialect}

# Needed by Hibernate3 Maven Plugin defined in pom.xml
hibernate.connection.username=${jdbc.username}
hibernate.connection.password=${jdbc.password}
hibernate.connection.url=${jdbc.url}
hibernate.connection.driver_class=${jdbc.driverClassName}
```

properties configured in pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <dbunit.dataTypeFactoryName>org.dbunit.ext.oracle.OracleDataTypeFactory</dbunit.dataTypeFactoryName>
    <dbunit.schema>SYSTEM</dbunit.schema>
    <hibernate.dialect>org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</hibernate.dialect>

    <jdbc.groupId>com.oracle</jdbc.groupId>
    <jdbc.artifactId>ojdbc14</jdbc.artifactId>
    <jdbc.version>10.2.0.3.0</jdbc.version>
    <jdbc.driverClassName>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</jdbc.driverClassName>
    <jdbc.url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@${oracle.host}:1521:${oracle.sid}</jdbc.url>
    <jdbc.username>*******</jdbc.username>
    <jdbc.password>*******</jdbc.password>
</properties>
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear : _Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)_

Comment: Do you have an idea how and where is `jdbc.password` defined? Is there a `PropertyPlaceholderResolver` or something similar in there?

Comment: The password is defined in the Pom and set in applicationContext.xml and jdbc.properties

Comment: What strange is I'm not using local db nor the root user. Also, it works when run as a war, but not unassembled; jetty:run.

Comment: I think, it is not able to locate database properties file in classpath. Where these variables (${jdbc.driverClassName}) are ? and where that file in located in application ?

Comment: Sorry if any of this seem trival, but java/spring/maven is not my expertise.  Anyhow, I noticed that if I change the dataSource name to dataSource2 and it ref in sessionFactory, I get errors caused by "No bean named 'dataSource2' is defined".  The dataSource is configured in applicationContext-resources.xml while sessionFactory in applicationContext.xml;  looks like its not accessing it when doing a jetty:run?

Answer (score 0):

So, after much research and lot of trial and error, it looks like the culprit was the jetty-maven-plugin.  The project was using version 6.1.9 and I promptly changed that to 6.1.26 when I realized that it didn't allow for war-overlays when doing jetty:run.  This resulted in the above error.

Through trial and error, I was able to determine that there was an issue with the dataSource bean and the applicationContext-resources.xml file.  Commenting out the bean definition in the xml file should have resulted in a BeanCreationException when trying to create the sessionFactory as the dataSource was not defined.  This, however, proved to be untrue and resulted in the same error, meaning it was referring to a different dataSource, presumable configured as a default in Spring?  Not sure at this point.  Renaming the dataSource to dataSource2 resolved the issue, but I didn't like the solution.

Reading more about the jetty plugin, I decided to migrate to the latest version of jetty 7.  I had initially decided to stay with 6 cause I didn't want too many changes at once, but moving to 7 proved to be a wise decision.  The issues with the dataSource files immediately went away.  This lead to the next set of issues, with struts.  Seems that we are overriding and reusing the package names for default and admin in our struts.xml.  This, again, works fine with run-war or run-exploded, but with run it causes struts errors.  We are currently using appfuse version 2.0.2, but I am thinking about updating that as well.

Once I was able to get around the struts issue, I was presented with problems with web.xml.  We've been using resource filtering to dynamically set some values in our web.xml and a couple jsp's.  This is an issue with jetty:run as it assumes webapp files are static and does not apply the resource filtering.  Using the  tag I was able to tell jetty and the war plugin to use a resource filtered version of web.xml.  The jsp's were another issue though.

A little googling and I found .  Using a properties file, I was able to apply resource filtering to is and then using spring, read values from the properties file when accessing the jsp.  Finally, I am able to get jetty:run to fire up my app.  However, now it seems I am getting PermGen space errors when it tries to hot-swap code.  Looks like it goes through multiple attmepts of restarting and eventually results in PermGen errors.  I'm currently setting the PermGen size to -XX:PermSize=64M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M.  Guess its more trial and error time.